# Edit Android navbar permanently by `settings put secure`

Tags: debugging, adb

`settings put secure sysui_nav_bar "key(82:file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/Data/Awe-Inspiring/menu.png),back;home;recents,menu_ime,key(120:file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/Data/Awesome/screenshot.png)`"

this doesn't work at all on my on F-droid's Termux on my Moto G Stylus XT 2043-4. or even LADB natively or even PC... adb command to edit navbar permanently

i run `adb connect` then w/e my ip address is to enable wifi debugging. then `adb shell`...

then my code. i get zero errors. but nothing changes. what gives? this used to work on my moto g 5 plus. is it because i'm not rooted? on my g stylus?

btw. i used file commander a 3rd party file explorer to access fully android/data... and make two custom folders